# Prove the following statement : $a * 0 = 0$. In the proof below, I do not understand the step where they used the replacement property.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, integers, axioms

[image]There is something that I do not understand about the proof below. In the third line, the answer key says that they used the replacement property but I do not see how this is an application of the replacement property. For example, the replacement property is : $a = b$, thus $c + a$ can be rewritten as $c + b$. In the proof, they just added $-(a \cdot 0)$ on both sides which is mathematically correct but it doesn't seem like the replacement property to me. Can someone explain to me how adding $-(a \cdot 0)$ to both sides is the replacement? Thank you.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Can you add the "first five" axioms?

Comment: It's the replacement property in the sense that they have $x=z \Rightarrow x+y=(x\mapsto z)+y=z+y$. But it's just a basic property of equality that you can do the same thing to both sides (indiscernibility of identicals, $x=z\Rightarrow f(x)=f(z)$), so it's hardly worth mentioning the logical rule used.

Comment: I don't see how the attached screenshot is relevant but based on how you are describing the replacement property, all the person did was add $-(a \cdot 0)$ to both sides, just like how the replacement property says if $a=b$ then you can add $c$ to both sides. That's all.

Comment: "on both sides which is mathematically correct "  Here's a question for you.  *Why* is it mathematically correct to add the same thing to both sides? Which axiom are you using when you do so?

Comment: @fleablood That is exactly why I asked this question. Because I don't understand why it is correct and what axiom they use. They say that they're using the replacement property which I'm not sure to understand. but I guess ill just memorize that adding something to both sides is the replacement property.

Comment: The replacement property is that if you have two expressions that describe the same object (such as $a =b$ so $a$ and $b$ are the same thing; or in this case $a0$ and $a0+a0$ are the exact same thing) then for any expression that uses one you can replace one with the other.  For example "I like to squish $a$ between my toes" can be stated as "I like to squish $b$ between my toes" because $a$ and $b$ are both the exact same thing.  ANd that is why "adding something to both sides" is valid.

Comment: But I have to see that I'm very confused as to how you can see $a=b$ therefore $c+a=c+b$ is an example of the replacement property but $0a + 0a = 0a$ therefore $(0a+0a)+ (-0a) = (0a) + (-0a)$ is not.  To me those two seem *EXACTLY* the same idea.  Why do they seem different to you.

Comment: .... BTW and FWIW.... I would criticize this proof for skipping what I would consider step 3:  I think there needs to be a step where one says "$-0\cdot a$ is an integer and actually exists.  ($0a$ exists because multiplication is closed for integers. And $-0a$ exists by existence of additive inverse axiom.... although I suppose if you had to mention closure property every time you add or multiply something it would drive every one nuts.)

Comment: @fleablood wow you're right. these are the exact same statement. I don't know why  I wasn't able to see it was the same thing. I think maybe its because its easier to read letters like a,b and c. I feel dumb now ,ahaha. But thank you for explaining me. now i truly understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A= a\cdot 0 + a\cdot 0$, let $B = a\cdot 0$, and let $C= -(a\cdot 0)$.

Then the line in question is
$A=B \implies A+C = B+C$, which is how you described the replacement property right?